# How to use vtk to add a coordinate axis to the window? the scale represents the pixel coordinates of the image in the window

Tags: c++, vtk

As shown in FIG:
[image]

I don't know how to achieve the effect on the image, can anyone tell me

I used vtkChartXY, but the image cannot be displayed on it

Here is the code:

```
    vtkNew<vtkChartXY> chart;
    vtkNew<vtkTable> table;
    vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> arrX;
    arrX->SetName("posX");
    table->AddColumn(arrX);
    vtkNew<vtkDoubleArray> arrY;
    arrY->SetName("posY");
    table->AddColumn(arrY);
    table->SetNumberOfRows(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        table->SetValue(i, 0, i - 500);
        table->SetValue(i, 1, i - 500);
    }
    auto chartPoints = chart->AddPlot(vtkChart::POINTS);
    chartPoints->SetInputData(table, 0, 1);

    view_->GetScene()->AddItem(chart);
    view_->GetRenderer()->AddActor(icosahedron_actor);
        view_->GetRenderer()->SetBackground(0.8, 0.0, 0.4);
        view_->Render();
```